# Is it possible to get the value if I use value="#"

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to use this

```
<select name="Interior Details" id="Interior" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
```

and the last option I use is `value=#`, but if I use this I cannot get the value.

I want to do like this, but it shouts "the html does not exist" when I click on the kitchen option.

```
 <select required="" name="Furniture" id="Furniture" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Furniture</option>
    <option value="kitchen">Kitchen Set</option>
    <option value="meja">Meja Bar</option>
    <option value="living room.html">Go to Living Room</option>
```

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Currently when I select kitchen, it's successfully redirect on kitchen page. But if you don't want to redirect if value "#" then you have to write check value before assign to href.

Comment: can u give me some example?

Comment: Convert the space for the URL properly - encode it

Answer (score 0):

I have modify your code for check "#" if it will find "#"" then it will not redirect.

```
<select required="" name="Furniture" id="Furniture" onChange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value!='#' ? this.options[this.selectedIndex].value :'' ;" >
    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Furniture</option>
    <option value="kitchen">Kitchen Set</option>
    <option value="meja">Meja Bar</option>
    <option value="living room.html">Go to Living Room</option>
```

Comment: does the code successfully redirect to the living room.html when i select it?

Comment: yes, but you have to use underscore in page name like living_room.html instead of using space.

Comment: Currently browser behaving like living%20room.html page

Comment: i keep redirecting while i click on the kitchen. am i doing it wrong? 
I do not want to redirect when I click kitchen

Comment: if option value is Kitchen then behavior is correct. if you don't want to redirect then change option value to #

Comment: so if I change the kitchen value to "#", kitchen does not have value

Comment: yes, what you need to do exactly ? as per my answer your requirement is fulfilled. You have to manage or modify yourself based on your requirement.

Comment: I am helping you to achieve your goal based on your effort. I am not writing your code.